# Multithreading in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opencv

I'm trying to multithread some OpenCV4Android code.  I divide a 432x432 image into 9 144x144 segments and pass each to a different thread:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        threads[3*i+j] = new Thread(new MyThread(image.rowRange(144*i, 144*(i+1)).colRange(144*j, 144*(j+1))));
        threads[3*i+j].start();
    }
}

for (Thread thread : threads) try {thread.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {};
```

Here is the thread class:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    final Mat block;

    public MyThread(Mat block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    public void run() {
        /* do image processing on block */
        Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(19,19));
        Mat closed = new Mat();
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(block, closed, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel);
        Core.divide(block, closed, block, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
        Core.normalize(block, block, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);
        block.convertTo(block, CvType.CV_8UC1);     
        Imgproc.threshold(block, block, -1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    }
}
```

I have two issues:

1. Although the threads are modifying the individual blocks correctly, the modifications are not showing up in the final image.  This would make sense if `Mat block` were passed by value to the thread, but Java should be passing its reference to the thread instead.
2. The runtime is *longer* than the unthreaded code - in my emulator, it goes up from ~1200 to ~1500 ms.  Is this a problem with the emulator, or is multithreading a really bad idea here for some reason?

Comment: Maybe your emulator only runs one thread at a time, but real hardware might run more.

Comment: Actually, on further Googling, you're right - the emulator [doesn't support multiple threads](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8024/improve-android-emulator-performance-on-windows-7-x64).

Comment: I don't know why your image isn't updating. I've never used OpenCV, but the documentation I've read in the last 5 minutes definitely suggests that the `Mat` is not copied and is operated on in-place. Sorry, that's as much as I can do, time for bed!

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? Your code works as expected when you do not multi-thread it. When you do multi-thread it, and run it in the emulator, it actually runs as it would in a single-core processor, the threads executing one after another, and that's slower than not multi-threading. But now the image data is not updated properly. Have you tried it in in a real target, not the emulator? And, what happens if you use the multi-thread code, but reduce the maximum number of threads created to 1?

Comment: No idea about Java, but that `final Mat block` doesn't mean it cannot be modified? If true, this line of code `this.block = block;` will create a new copy of the Mat object., which will be lost after thread.join().

Comment: Sammy, `final Mat block` creates a "blank final", explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java), which can be initialised precisely once, and only in a constructor method. The `final` applies to the value of the pointer `block` which can only ever point to one specific `Mat` object. However, the data internal to the `Mat` object can be mutable. Nice try, but not, I suspect, the answer!

Comment: In any case, I can take the `final` away with no change.  Alright, looks like I'm going to have to debug in a really painful way, since there's no obvious problem I've missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've no experience with OpenCV, so I'll address only the second issue.

A thread needs a CPU to run (or a core which acts as a virtual CPU). So, you will never have more threads running in silmultaneous then the real number of cores available in the device.

Let's assume you have a device with 2 cores and you split the work in 9 threads. The final result is that only 2 out of 9 threads will run in silmultaneous, while the remaining 7 will be in the queue waiting for their turn to have CPU.

As there is a cost in Thread creation and switching, the overall performance result would be worse then having only 2 threads.

If you are spliting the work between threads for performance reasons, don't make more threads then the number of cores in the device.

I believe that most devices on market are limited to 1 or 2 cores ...

Regards

Comment: Maybe I'll try 3 instead of 9, then.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1718522/1397061) says that more than 1 thread per core is optimal in some situations.

Comment: The best way is to test and measure. From your post it looks like you are sharing between the threads a pre-loaded image (so no I/O on this part). If the OpenCV isn't performing any I/O, probably you will get to the number of cores.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem was being caused by the conversion of the `block` Mat to a different type in this section:

```
Core.divide(block, closed, block, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
Core.normalize(block, block, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);
block.convertTo(block, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

I'm not sure why this should be a problem, but I fixed it by storing the intermediate floating-point matrix in `closed` and only putting the final answer back into `block`:

```
Core.divide(block, closed, closed, 1, CvType.CV_32F);
Core.normalize(closed, block, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);
```

Answer (score 0):

Luis has addressed the second problem. And i think the first issue is because that you process a new Mat to the thread, the modification on the new Mat will not effect the old one.

I find the source code of rowRange, there is some native code but clearly it creates a new object.

```
 public Mat rowRange(int startrow, int endrow)
 {

     Mat retVal = new Mat(n_rowRange(nativeObj, startrow, endrow));

     return retVal;
 }
```

Comment: It creates a new object, but that object internally points to (some of) the same data as the old object.  I'm able to modify `image` through `block` when there is only one thread.