# print libuv threadpool size in node js 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, libuv

[This link](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html) purely specifies that `libuv` provides a thread pool which can be used to run user code and get notified in the loop thread. Its default size is 4, but it can be changed at startup time by setting the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` environment variable to any value. (the absolute maximum is 128).

So, in `package.json`, I set `scripts` field as below (**NOTE**: I am using Windows 7, Node JS 8.11.3, nodemon, express 4.16),

Code snippet from `package.json`

```json
.
.
.
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 120 && node index.js",
  },
.
.
.
```

Code for `index.js`

```javascript
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('LIBUV Threads: ', process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE); // this returns 'undefined'
});
```

How can I be assured that thread pool size is set? I want to print it out here in `index.js` as above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't have spaces in your `set` command.

```
set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=120 && node index.js
```

Also you should start your Node.js program by invoking the `start` script:

```
npm start
```

Otherwise the environmental variable won't be set and you will continue to get `undefined` when accessing it in your code.

If you are using Nodemon, you can ensure your npm script is invoked by running the command with an extra argument:

```
nodemon --exec npm start
```

Comment: Thanks for that rectification, but still I get `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please try the same command but using only 1 ampersand (&)?

Comment: Yup! I did and result is unaffected. Also, I doubt whether `process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` is the right way to print the libuv thread pool in node js

Comment: Do you start your server with `npm start`?

Comment: I use `nodemon`, it automatically identifies the `start` script.

Comment: Did you try running *just* `npm start`? `nodemon` looks for `index.js` if it is run without arguments (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Yeah! you are absolutely correct. It worked! can you update your answer with proper directions, so that I will accept it? also I will update my question with more details

Comment: but how do we actually see if the config gets picked up, I am working on windows so some of the linux commands arent fetching my purpose.