# outofmemoryexception: threads using too much virtual memory, about 12GB

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep

actually i have to create lots of threads to send pcap file using UDP protocol, when thread completely sends the pcap file it then sleep for some time. when i sleep thread to 420 seconds virtual memory gets full after creating more than 3100 threads and program throws a OutOfMemoryException.

i searched internet about this problem but found that a thread takes only 1MB to create and pcap file is just 60KB, and my 3100 threads are consuming more than 12GB(1.06*3100<12GB). on the other hand physical memory is not used more than 200MB. i have to create more than 5000 threads at the same time

what am i doing wrong? can anyone help me?

thanks

my code:

```
public static void send_pcap_file_with_single_port()
    {
        string callID = Call_ID;
        try
        {
            //CREATING CONNECTION HERE
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("g711a.pcap", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {


                for (Pos = 0; Pos < (StreamBytes - ChunkSize); Pos += ChunkSize)
                {
                    //creating RTP_header here

                    stream.Read(RTP_payload, 0, ChunkSize);
                    //combining both the byte arrays
                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(RTP_header, 0, Bytes_to_send, 0, RTP_header.Length);
                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(RTP_payload, 0, Bytes_to_send, 16, RTP_payload.Length);

                    RTPpacket_queue.Enqueue(Bytes_to_send);
                    //RTP_handler.Send(Bytes_to_send, Bytes_to_send.Length, remote_EP);
                }

                //done processing here
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();

                RTP_count++;
                GC.Collect();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(420000);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream_logFile))
            //{
            //    sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            //}
            //send_BYE_message_toSIPp(client, "BYE", 5060, 2, callID);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

creating threads here:

```
Thread RTP_sender = new Thread(new ThreadStart(send_pcap_file_with_single_port));
                            RTP_sender.Start();
```

Comment: threading is very expensive and yes, each thread takes around 1MB at a minimum. what are you trying to do here? Show some code. I would rather put the threads on the threadpool and let the threadpool take care of managing the threads for you. obviously your code can be improved but we need to see it before we can suggest anything. I do not see any reason why you need to create such a large number of threads

Comment: 3100 threads?  How many CPUs do you have?

Comment: btw 60KB is not 0.6MB its 0.06 MB, you have to post some code

Comment: By using *fewer* threads you will be able to do *more* work as you save time on thread context switching. It will be easier to debug as well. In fact 1-worker-thread applications are often faster than their multi-threaded alternatives.

Comment: @Vajura, sorry, my mistake

Comment: You do not HAVE to create more than 5000 threads; in fact, if a thread you've created is going to be sleeping for 420 seconds, it may just has well simply be destroyed. I think it should be possible to re-design your code to make use of the fact that a thread that sleeps for that long is not doing anything other than using up precious memory.

Comment: @SineNomen actually i have to send other packets right after 420 seconds, that's why i am sending thread on sleep for 420 seconds

Comment: I would suggest reading [Optimal number of threads per core](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1718465/434949)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, i wrote the code, can you suggest me something now?

Comment: can anyone answer me why are these threads taking too much memory, i just want that answer, i will figure out the solution myself, i am not asking you people to suggest me a solution, just explain me why these threads are taking that much virtual memory.
thanks

Comment: Goes to show that no matter how fantastically many resources a modern computer provides, an inept programmer can always exhaust them.  The GC.Collect() call does not do what you think it does.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034).

Comment: you are missing one part of your sample code - where and how you are creating threads. right now, you just show 1 thread being created... but how are they being created? And I would also read @HansPassant's post too.

Comment: @Afshan Rafaqat: The answer is -- they are not using up too much memory; you are simply creating too many threads. That is and always has been the answer. Simple analogy: If I buy 10,000 coffee mugs, obviously I am not going to have enough storage in my kitchen cabinets to store all those mugs. The problem lies not in the kitchen cabinets or in the fact objects take up space, having a volume and mass... the problem lies in the fact I just bought 10,000 mugs. Don't buy 10,000 mugs. Don't create 5000 threads.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms you exhaust you garbage collector by creating objects in long term pile (objects that survive longer then few seconds). Fix would be to free and recreate thread when it is needed.

In any case by default i5 has 2 cores, if you have 3 or more threads than they are running them on same cpu. Running 3000+ of them means 1500 each, it is not a problem unless they try to write in same place (in case they start blocking like hell).

Comment: dont i5s have 4 cores?

Comment: i just want to fix the virtual memory issue, can you suggest a solution, thanks

Comment: Several people have suggested the very same solution -- re-design the logic of your program. You're just not accepting that solution.

Comment: @margus
thanks for your response but how can i free and recreate thread when it is in sleep mode?

Comment: Actually, you really do NOT need 5000 threads for this. Just experimented with it a bit myself and even 5000 objects with TEMPORARY background threads causes major issues. You need to re-think your logic from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate you do not need 5000 permanent threads to accomplish something like this, I have created a sample program.

The program does not do much really but what it does do is that it creates 5000 objects, each of which creates a thread when it needs to do its work. There isn't any actual work being done other than simply sleeping for a random interval but still.

Just run the program, leave it running for a while and keep an eye on its memory use. You will see it is very much manageable while still actually doing work on 5000 objects.

You will probably need to actually be creative in applying this approach to your situation but you could do something along the lines of what I am doing.

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;

    public static class MainClass
    {
        public static Random sleeper = new Random ();

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch ();
            List<WorkerClass> workload = new List<WorkerClass> ();

            // Create a workload of 5000 objects
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                workload.Add (new WorkerClass ());
            }

            int fires = 0;
            // Start processing the workload
            while (true) {
                // We'll measure the time it took to go through the entire workload
                // to illustrate that it does not take all that long.
                timer.Restart ();
                foreach (WorkerClass w in workload) {
                    // for each of the worker objects in the entire workload
                    // we decrease its internal counter by 1.
                    // Because after the loop is done, we sleep for 1 secondd
                    // that amounts to reducing the counter by 1 every second.
                    w.counter--;
                    if (w.counter == 0) {
                        fires++;
                        // Once the counter hits 0, do the work.
                        w.DoWork ();
                    }
                }
                timer.Stop ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Processing the entire workload of {0} objects took {1} milliseconds, {2} workers actually fired.", workload.Count, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, fires);
                fires = 0;
                Thread.Sleep (1000);
            }
        }
    }

    public class WorkerClass
    {
        public int counter = 0;

        public WorkerClass ()
        {
            // When the worker is created, set its internal counter
            // to a random value between 5 and 10.
            // This is to mimic sleeping it for a random interval.
            // Also see the primary loop in MainClass.Main
            this.counter = MainClass.sleeper.Next (5, 10);
        }

        public void DoWork ()
        {
            // Whenever we do the work, we'll create a background worker thread
            // that actually does the work.
            BackgroundWorker work = new BackgroundWorker ();
            work.RunWorkerCompleted += (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) => {
                // This simulates going back to sleep for a random interval, see
                // the main loop in MainClass.Main
                this.counter = MainClass.sleeper.Next (5, 10);
            };
            work.DoWork += (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) => {
                // Simulate working by sleeping a random interval
                Thread.Sleep (MainClass.sleeper.Next (2000, 5000));
            };
            // And now we actually do the work.
            work.RunWorkerAsync ();
        }
    }
}
```