# Why does more workers than processors in Multiprocessing Python improve runtime?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, cpu-speed

I am playing around with [concurrent.future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) in python as a means to understand a few simple implementations that use multiprocessing. However, I've come across a very unexpected result. Before I begin, here are my system details:

Computer Type: Laptop w/ Windows 10

Ram: 8.00 GB

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U @ 2.60GHzBase Speed: 2.80 GHz

Sockets: 1

Cores: 2

Logical Processors: 4

L1 cache: 128KB

L2 cache: 512KB

L3 cache: 4.0MB

Take the following geometric series that computes the mean of `n` numbers:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr0Im.png]

With this idea in mind, I create a function that computes the mean of the integers between a low bound `a` (inclusive) and a high bound `b` (exclusive). I then run a test **with** and **without** multiprocessing on a range of 500 million integers:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

def mean(a, b):
    total_sum = 0
    for next_int in range(a, b):
        total_sum += next_int
    return total_sum / (b - a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 500000000              # 500 Million
    wall_time = time.time()
    base_ans = mean(0, n)      # From 0 to n-1.
    print("Single Thread Time: " + str(time.time() - wall_time) + " sec.")

    work = [(0, int(n/2)), (int(n/2), n)]
    num_workers = 2            # One process per core!
    test_ans = 0
    wall_time = time.time()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_workers) as executor:
        future_tasks = {executor.submit(mean, job[0], job[1]): job for job in work}
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks):
            test_ans += future.result()

    print("Multiprocessing Time: " + str(time.time() - wall_time) + " sec.")
    print(str(base_ans) + " == " + str(test_ans / num_workers) + " => " + str(base_ans == (test_ans / num_workers)))
```

The following produces the following output:

```
Single Thread Time: 41.0769419670105 sec.     # CPU Utilization ≈ 35% (from task manager)
Multiprocessing Time: 24.71605634689331 sec.  # CPU Utilization ≈ 70% (from task manager)
```

As we can clearly see, a major speed up was observed (**roughly 1.66x**). However, if I create 4 workers, instead of 2, I get an even greater speed up:

```
work = [(0, int(n/4)), (int(n/4), int(n/2)), (int(n/2), int(3*n/4)), (int(3*n/4), n)]
num_workers = 4
# ...
Single Thread Time: 41.51883292198181 sec.     # CPU Utilization ≈ 35% (from task manager)
Multiprocessing Time: 18.18532919883728 sec.  # CPU Utilization = 100% (from task manager)
```

An even greater speed up can be seen here (**roughly 2.28x**) and it is even consist over many runs!

1. Since only two processes can simultaneously run on this two (physical) core system, **is the efficiency of Window's scheduler the reason for this continued speed up?**
2. How can I choose a `max_worker` number that provides the fastest runtime? How many more processes should I add past the physical core count?
3. And lastly, does adding more processes past the physical core count affect the threads (in multithreading) within each process from running efficiency?

Comment: You realize logical processors do provide an actual speed up in many cases, right? Sure, the gain isn't as big, but it's non-zero (up to 30% in ideal cases). They didn't just make [hyperthreaded chips for no reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading#Performance_claims).

Comment: This answer may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718465/optimal-number-of-threads-per-core